# Can't find what is setting my text color when using LESS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm new to using LESS and I'm not 100% sure where I need to make the change for my main text color.

I'm using Bootstrap as well as the Cerulean theme from Bootswatch.com. The two Cerulean LESS files are in my Content\LESS\bootstrap folder. My default text is coming out as #317EAC but I was asked to change it to black #000000. When I view a page and look at the F12 Dev tools it looks like the text color is set in the Body section of my site.css file. That file is being compiled from my LESS files.

My Site.less file is importing the Bootstrap less file on the very first line. This is what I had initially in my Site.less file.

```
@import "LESS/bootstrap/bootstrap";

@font-family:       "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
@text-color:        #317EAC;
@font-size-base:    14px;

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

This is what I changed it to but it's not changing the text to black.

```
@import "LESS/bootstrap/bootstrap";

@font-family:       "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
@text-color:        #000000 
@font-size-base:    14px;

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: @text-color !important;
}
```

After I specifically compile my Site.less and look at my Site.css the Body tag still has the #317EAC color set. It must be getting set somewhere else but I can't seem to find where that is. Plus, I thought setting the !important on the color tag in my Site.less would make it override anything else?

I even changed my variable.less file to the below settings. The @text-color is inheriting from the @gray-base which should be black.

Also note that I cleared my browser cache as well and that didn't help.

Anyone have a suggestion on where I would change my text color?

Here is a screen shot of my F12 tools.
[image]

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after the variable assignment: `@text-color:        #000000 `

Comment: let me know if that fixes it

Comment: Good catch but unfortunately that didn't do the trick.

Comment: You need to check what classes are been applied to this element. Problaly  there's an overload from some other style.
Please, could you paste the HTML hierarchy and what styles are been applied?

Comment: @CarlosAraujo not sure I know what you would like to copy but I will try get what I can. It's on the Body tag though. Using the F12 tools it tells me its coming from the Site.css file. That's why I thought that using the !important the Body tag of my Site.less it would override where ever it is being set else where. From my understanding since I do the Bootstrap import at the top of the Site.less that anything I write afterwards should take precedence as well. I will say that I see two Body tags in my compiled Site.css so the body being set in multiple places...I just don't know exactly where.

Comment: First, I probably wouldn't set !important on body color property. Anyways, if you inspect your body tag in the browser do you see black being defined somewhere and overridden (something like this https://www.evernote.com/l/AIg_83r53uNHXLq1xsN-9hqlFO7rVoKMiG0). Another thing I can think of is are you using a CMS? Wordpress or Drupal has CSS caching sometimes enabled that you'll need to flush in order to see changes.

Comment: Can you open the dev tools and possibly post a screenshot of it?

Comment: I'm going to see if I can figure out how to post a screen shot

Comment: I think I found where it might be setting it. Looks like the scaffolding.less is where it's set but it has body { color: #text-color }. The #text-color is in the variable.less file and my site.less file. I have them both set to Black (#000). Even so, I thought that since my Site.less file first imports Bootstrap and then I set the @text-color afterwards it should pick up the setting in my Site.less file.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my F12 tools.

Comment: @jerrylow this is an Asp.Net MVC site. No WordPress or Drupal or even an external theme other than Cerulean from Bootswatch.com. I only used the !important to see if I could get it to force the color.

Comment: Double check if the less files are been compiled into css.

Comment: I deleted the Site.css and that caused a little issue but I just pulled back a server copy from TFS. I then made a small change to one of my settings in Site.less and the site seemed to pick that up. Unfortunately it sill doesn't have the black text. I'm at a complete loss as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Wait, this might be a stupid question your file is getting recompiled right? If you look into the outputted site.css and look at `body {}` are you changes there?

Comment: @jerrylow, no the changes aren't there. I think they are coming from the scaffold.less file and even when I code Black directly there the old color still gets compile. However, I have another css property in my Site.less file where I changed the value from Blue to Red, recompiled, and the Site.css got updated. That leads me to believe the compile is working....just not for the Body property. Crazy.....

Comment: In your screenshot there aren't the `padding` styles you have defined in the body, something is wrong is that file, can you show us full `site.less` file?

Comment: First off I want to say Thank You! to everyone that hung in here and gave me suggestions. Your help is always appreciated more than you know. Second, for what ever reason it seems to be working now. I did so many little things yesterday I'm not sure what might have fixed it. All I can think of is that I deleted the Site.css out of my project and then recompiled my Site.less. Visual Studio complained about the file so I got an older copy off of our TFS. Then I went back through and re-added my LESS settings again. Saved, restarted VS, cleared cache, and it works this morning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to install less compiler like proposed. After that, you have to drag your project on this less compiler and compile your less file into CSS.